# what does different color of nodes in decision tree classifier sklearn indicate?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to visualize the output of decision tree classifier. This is my code

```
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
tree.plot_tree(dt2,filled=True,fontsize=8)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('dtree.jpg')
```

This is the image I got. [image]

What does these colors represent? How should I interpret them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`plot_tree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) for its `filled` parameter:

> **filled: bool, default=False**
> When set to True, paint nodes to indicate majority class for classification, extremity of values for regression, or purity of node for multi-output.

So in classification tasks, the color indicates to which class the majority of the samples at each node belong to.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the documentation, but perhaps obvious from the output: the darker the color, the more pure that node (akin to the docs note about multi-output).